# jquery switch to change what list is appended to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, switch-statement

I am creating a case / break loop to change what ul a new li will be created in. I have gotten pretty close but when I change the variable to reassign where the li should render the value stored in the variable stacks. Eventually you can only add the li to every ul there is an option for.

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton|Baloo+Tammudu" 
rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-
1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
src="file:///C:/Users/Will/Desktop/JS_Test/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class=app>
        <div id=menu_container> <div id=menu_title> Menu </div>


            <input id="ListInput" /></input>

            <button id="AddToList">Add</button>

            </input>
              <select id="GroceryType" list=hosting-plan>
              <option>Select</option>
              <option name=produce value=1>Produce</option>
              <option name=baking value=2>Baking</option>
                <option name=meat value=3>Meat</option>
                <option name=dairy value=4>Dairy</option>
                <option name=frozen value=5>Frozen</option>
                <option name=etc value=6>Etc</option>

              </select>
        </div>


        <div id=list_container><div id=list_title> Grocery List </div>

        <div class=sublist_container>  

          <ul id="Produce">
Produce
          </ul>

          <ul id="Baking">
Baking
          </ul>

          <ul id="Meat">
Meat
          </ul>

          <ul id="Dairy">
Dairy
          </ul>

          <ul id="Frozen">
Frozen
          </ul>

          <ul id="Etc">
Etc
          </ul>

            </div>
        </div>             
    </div>
</body>
```

Then the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#GroceryType").change(function () {
    let val = $(this).val();
    console.log(val);

    switch (val) {
        case '1':
        $('#AddToList').click(function(){
        $('#Produce').append($('<li>', {
     text: $('#ListInput').val()
            }));
    });

         break;

        case '2':
        $('#AddToList').click(function(){
        $('#Baking').append($('<li>', {
     text: $('#ListInput').val()
            }));
    });

         break;

         case '3':
        $('#AddToList').click(function(){
        $('#Meat').append($('<li>', {
     text: $('#ListInput').val()
            }));
    });

        break;

        case '4':
        $('#AddToList').click(function(){
        $('#Dairy').append($('<li>', {
     text: $('#ListInput').val()
            }));
    });


        break;

        case '5':
        $('#AddToList').click(function(){
        $('#Frozen').append($('<li>', {
     text: $('#ListInput').val()
            }));
    });


        break;

        case '6':
        $('#AddToList').click(function(){
        $('#Dairy').append($('<li>', {
     text: $('#ListInput').val()
            }));
    });

    } 
});
```

});

And finally some CSS:

```
            .app{
                width: 100%;
                height: 1400px;
                background-color: #d3c9bc;
                position:relative;

            }

            #menu_container, #list_container{
                position: absolute;
                top: 10em;
                width: 25em;
                    padding: 1em;
                background-color: #e59b80;
            }

            #menu_container{
                position:relative;
                left: 30%;
                height: 5em;
                top: 2em;

            }

            #menu_title{
                background-color: #e5e580;
                position: absolute;
                width:40%;
                left:32%;
                text-align:center;
            }

            #AddToList{
                position: absolute;
                top: 40%;
                left:10%;
            }

            #ListInput{
                position:absolute;
                top: 40%;
                left: 20%;
                width:60%;
            }

            #GroceryType{
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 15%;
                left:15%;

            }

            #list_title{
                background-color: #e5e580;
                position: absolute;
                width:40%;
                left:32%;
                text-align:center;
            }

            #list_container{
                top: 10em;
                left: 30%;
                min-height: 40em;
                max-height: 200em;
            }

            #Produce, #Meat, #Baking, #Dairy, #Frozen, #Etc{
                min-width: 10em;
                min-height:1em;
                background-color: #9fe580;
                overflow-wrap: break-word;
                word-break: break-word;
                word-wrap: break-word;
                hyphens: auto;

            }

            .sublist_container{
                position: absolute;
                top: 15%;
                left: 10%;
                height: 30em;
                width: 75%;
                background-color: #80e5b2;
            }
```

It almost works but I need the variable for the list types to only handle the events 1 option at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to remove the click event before you change it, thats why it is stacking. Also I changed how the append parameters look...**

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#GroceryType").change(function() {
    let val = $(this).val();
    console.log(val);
    $('#AddToList').off('click');//this is new
    switch (val) {
      case '1':
        $('#AddToList').click(function() {
          $('#Produce').append('<li>'+$('#ListInput').val()+'</li>');//these all changed but can be done many ways
        });

        break;

      case '2':
        $('#AddToList').click(function() {
          $('#Baking').append('<li>'+$('#ListInput').val()+'</li>');
        });

        break;

      case '3':
        $('#AddToList').click(function() {
          $('#Meat').append('<li>'+$('#ListInput').val()+'</li>');
        });

        break;

      case '4':
        $('#AddToList').click(function() {
          $('#Dairy').append('<li>'+$('#ListInput').val()+'</li>');
        });


        break;

      case '5':
        $('#AddToList').click(function() {
          $('#Frozen').append('<li>'+$('#ListInput').val()+'</li>');
        });


        break;

      case '6':
        $('#AddToList').click(function() {
          $('#Dairy').append('<li>'+$('#ListInput').val()+'</li>');
        });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.app {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1400px;
  background-color: #d3c9bc;
  position: relative;
}

#menu_container,
#list_container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10em;
  width: 25em;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #e59b80;
}

#menu_container {
  position: relative;
  left: 30%;
  height: 5em;
  top: 2em;
}

#menu_title {
  background-color: #e5e580;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  left: 32%;
  text-align: center;
}

#AddToList {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 10%;
}

#ListInput {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 60%;
}

#GroceryType {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15%;
  left: 15%;
}

#list_title {
  background-color: #e5e580;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  left: 32%;
  text-align: center;
}

#list_container {
  top: 10em;
  left: 30%;
  min-height: 40em;
  max-height: 200em;
}

#Produce,
#Meat,
#Baking,
#Dairy,
#Frozen,
#Etc {
  min-width: 10em;
  min-height: 1em;
  background-color: #9fe580;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
}

.sublist_container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 10%;
  height: 30em;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: #80e5b2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton|Baloo+Tammudu" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-
1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/Users/Will/Desktop/JS_Test/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class=app>
    <div id=menu_container>
      <div id=menu_title> Menu </div>


      <input id="ListInput" /></input>

      <button id="AddToList">Add</button>

      </input>
      <select id="GroceryType" list=hosting-plan>
              <option>Select</option>
              <option name=produce value=1>Produce</option>
              <option name=baking value=2>Baking</option>
                <option name=meat value=3>Meat</option>
                <option name=dairy value=4>Dairy</option>
                <option name=frozen value=5>Frozen</option>
                <option name=etc value=6>Etc</option>

              </select>
    </div>


    <div id=list_container>
      <div id=list_title> Grocery List </div>

      <div class=sublist_container>

        <ul id="Produce">
          Produce
        </ul>

        <ul id="Baking">
          Baking
        </ul>

        <ul id="Meat">
          Meat
        </ul>

        <ul id="Dairy">
          Dairy
        </ul>

        <ul id="Frozen">
          Frozen
        </ul>

        <ul id="Etc">
          Etc
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are binding additional events to #AddToList for each time any of the cases in the switch is executed. So you will eventually have a bunch of events, all firing at the same time.

A quick fix would be to un-bind the existing event before you add the new one:

```
case '1':
    $('#AddToList').off().on('click',function(){
        $('#Produce').append($('<li>', {
            text: $('#ListInput').val()
        }));
    });
    break;
```

I would have attempted to write a little bit cleaner code, as well. You are repeating the same code over and over again, you could break that code out into a function:

```
function addToList(elementId) {
    $('#AddToList').off().on('click',function(){
        $('#'+elementId).append('<li>'+$('#ListInput').val()+'</li>');
    });
}
```

Then your switch would look like this:

```
case '1':
    addToList("Produce");
    break;
case '2':
    addToList("Baking");
    break;
case '3':
    addToList("Meat");
    break;
case '4':
    addToList("Dairy");
    break;
case '5':
    addToList("Frozen");
    break;
case '6':
    addToList("Etc");
    break;
```

You see how your code is now much cleaner and easier to read? And you can now update the code in just one place instead of many places.

Comment: This is a really great way to achieve this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try rewriting your problem statement. I am almost following but not completely sure I understand you. Will try to help, unless you have it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Removed the switch case using array operation. Also repaired the event to listen the add button click event rather than the dropdown change event. Run the following snippet to check the output.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#AddToList").on("click", function() {
    let val = $("#GroceryType").val();
    var ar = ["#Produce", "#Baking", "#Meat", "#Dairy", "#Frozen", "#Dairy"];
    var pos = parseInt(val);
    $item_name = $('#ListInput').val();
    $(ar[pos - 1]).append("<li>" + $item_name + "</li>");
  });
});
```

```css
.app {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1400px;
  background-color: #d3c9bc;
  position: relative;
}

#menu_container,
#list_container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10em;
  width: 25em;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #e59b80;
}

#menu_container {
  position: relative;
  left: 30%;
  height: 5em;
  top: 2em;
}

#menu_title {
  background-color: #e5e580;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  left: 32%;
  text-align: center;
}

#AddToList {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 10%;
}

#ListInput {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 60%;
}

#GroceryType {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15%;
  left: 15%;
}

#list_title {
  background-color: #e5e580;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  left: 32%;
  text-align: center;
}

#list_container {
  top: 10em;
  left: 30%;
  min-height: 40em;
  max-height: 200em;
}

#Produce,
#Meat,
#Baking,
#Dairy,
#Frozen,
#Etc {
  min-width: 10em;
  min-height: 1em;
  background-color: #9fe580;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
}

.sublist_container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 10%;
  height: 30em;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: #80e5b2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton|Baloo+Tammudu" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>
  <div class=app>
    <div id=menu_container>
      <div id=menu_title> Menu </div>
      <input id="ListInput" /></input>
      <button id="AddToList">Add</button>
      </input>
      <select id="GroceryType" list=hosting-plan>
  <option>Select</option>
  <option name=produce value=1>Produce</option>
  <option name=baking value=2>Baking</option>
  <option name=meat value=3>Meat</option>
  <option name=dairy value=4>Dairy</option>
  <option name=frozen value=5>Frozen</option>
  <option name=etc value=6>Etc</option>
 </select>
    </div>
    <div id=list_container>
      <div id=list_title> Grocery List </div>
      <div class=sublist_container>
        <ul id="Produce">
          Produce
        </ul>
        <ul id="Baking">
          Baking
        </ul>
        <ul id="Meat">
          Meat
        </ul>
        <ul id="Dairy">
          Dairy
        </ul>
        <ul id="Frozen">
          Frozen
        </ul>
        <ul id="Etc">
          Etc
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This works exactly how I hoped! I don't fully understand the script but its perfect food for thought  to learn. Thank you very much!

Comment: I am glad to hear that. Which part you are not understanding? Mark it as accepted answer if it fulfills your queries.